# Consumindo web service wsdl .net framework 2.0

Tags: c#, web-service, wsdl, http-status

Ao gerar a requisição com todos os parâmetros corretos eu tenho o retorno erro 307 temporary redirect. Algúem sabe me dizer o que este erro representa ?

Comment: Se você postar o código, o que está fazendo e em qual momento o erro acontece, fica mais fácil ajudar!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após diversos testes, descobri o erro acontecia porque o a url do configurada no projeto estava http , quando na verdade o web service usava a url https.
Bastou alterar para https e a comunicação passou acontecer.
Quando acontecia a requisição o servidor do web service fazia um redirect para a url com https para forçar o uso de https.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você está acessando uma url de um serviço terceiro. O codigo 307 significa que o serviço acredita que a url foi direcionada para outra url.

Você pode ler mais em:

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E307.html